# Can't see file changes inside Docker container

Tags: docker

Inside my Docker container I have a folder "data":

> /usr/local/data

There is a script running inside the same container that is successfully changing the content of data. Yet, when I log into the container it only shows the original contents:

```
docker exec -it da1fe0a1cb6a /bin/bash
cd /usr/local/data
```

=> Shows original content only

What am I doing wrong? Is there something that prevents "docker exec" from refreshing the folder contents? Or am I somehow attached to a temporary state of the container?

Comment: "There is a script running inside the same container that is successfully changing the content of data. ". Are you sure the script actually changes data? From your description it seems to me that script is not working.

Comment: @leopal: I'm certain that the files are there because the script is also copying the folder to S3 and then it continuously shows the new contents. It's only when I login to the container it shows the original contents only.

Comment: Whatever is there in the script, run it in verbose mode `set -x`. And check docker logs for those container. `docker logs <container-id>`